# What's the proper way to build a REAL WORLD app in python

Tags: python, wxpython

I've only been learning python for about half a year and I'm just now putting it all together and trying to make something useful...

I've completely built my GUI (using wxpython) now I need to create the back-end which I'm fully capable but, I'm kinda confused on how I should bind the two...

what is the structure I need to bind my real program within the GUI

Am I suppose to build the back-end in a separate file and import all the classes of my back-end program into the GUI program and call the functions/methods I need from there?

build all of the back-end into the GUI file?

keep them both separate and create a 3rd file that imports the GUI and back-end?

and what if I have functions that needs variables from the other (GUI needs a back-end variable and vice-versa)

Hopefully this is making sense as I can't find the best way to describe what logical issue I'm having